# Printing on BLE thermal printer

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, thermal-printer

I'm writing android app (with Kotlin) and need to print receip on thermal printer. The printer uses BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) protocol.

I successfully connect to the device and read it's services and characteristics but here comes the problem. I don't know which characteristic to use for printing and what exactly to write on that characteristic. I can not find any useful information about this topic. This is the services and characteristics that i discover on the printer:

```
Service UUID: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Service UUID: 0000ae30-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae10-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Service UUID: 0000ae3a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae3b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic UUID: 0000ae3c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Comment: Maybe you could at least tell the model name of your printer?

Comment: It's a cheap chinese printer. Does not have any brand or model. It's tha same like this one https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005217328442.html

Answer (score -1):

Please read this article:
https://werwolv.net/blog/cat_printer

This Characteristic is most likely to fit:
0000ae01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Comment: Need more detailed explanation